# How does the pointer of an iterator in C++ change in a loop?

Tags: c++, loops, pointers, iterator

I was playing around with `vector`s in C++, and I found this problem, I got quite confused...

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  vector<int> v;
  v.push_back(1);
  v.push_back(2);
  v.push_back(3);

  for (vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
  {
    printf("At: %p, %i\n", &it, *it);
  }
}
```

And I did ran this program

```
g++ -Wall soquestion.cpp -o soquestion
./soquestion
```

The output

```
At: 0x7fff59c80a98, 1
At: 0x7fff59c80a98, 2
At: 0x7fff59c80a98, 3
```

But I thought the addresses of the `it` was incremented each time??

Comment: The iterator is just a single temporary object that lives as long as the loop, so its address doesn't change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
printf("At: %p, %i\n", &*it, *it);
```

This will show you what I assume you want.  The address of the selected object in the vector followed by the value of the selected object in the vector.  Like duffymo said, previously you were referencing the actual `it` object itself instead of what it is pointing to.

Answer (score 2):

I would interpret the first value as the reference to the iterator object in memory, which isn't changing.  Once it's instantiated, the object reference is constant.

The second value is the index into the vector, which is incremented.  It's a private data member inside the iterator itself that's being incremented, not the iterator object.

I don't believe you're thinking about the iterator object correctly.

Comment: Not the index into the vector, but the iterated-over items (dereferenced iterator).

Comment: Yes, but you printed &it.  That's the reference to the iterator object, right?

Comment: I agree on your first paragraph (and the third one too, obviously OP is slightly confused), just not on the *wording* of your second paragraph (even though I know what you mean)... ;)

Comment: `&object` is the **address** of the object (unless the object's type overloads `operator&`, which is rare).

Comment: I can see what you mean by the reference to an iterator object. But for the second value, why does `*it` change? Aren't `it` the same `it`?

Comment: @duffymo `*it` is certainly no pointer, it is a reference to the item the iterator refers to.

Comment: @Juto the address of `it` doesn't change. It's object `it` 'points' to that changes when you increment it.

Answer (score 2):

The *pointer* or *iterator* object, i.e., `it` stays put as is nicely demonstrated by the output of `&it`. However, the pointer's or iterator's value get's incremented resulting in referencing the next value in the sequence. That's shown by `*it`.

If you want to see where the pointer/iterator actually point's to, you'd use `&*it`. If `it` is known to be a pointer you could print `it` directly:

```
std::cout << "&it=" << &it << " "
    "obj=" << &*it << " "
    "value=" << *it << "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

iterator address remains fixed in current scope

I think you wanted probably this :

```
printf("At: %p, %i\n", &*it, *it);
```

Comment: `soquestion.cpp:14: warning: format ‘%p’ expects type ‘void*’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’`

Answer (score 1):

Incrementing any object (even a pointer) doesn't change the address of that object. If it's a pointer, incrementing it changes the address it points to, but the address of the pointer itself is still the same.  For example in this code, the same address (the address of `b`) is printed twice.

```
int a;
int* b = &a;
std::cout << &b << std::endl;
++b;
std::cout << &b << std::endl;
```

An iterator isn't necessarily a pointer though, it's just some object that overloads the necessary operators to act somewhat like a pointer (at least `*`, `++` and `==`, though sometimes others as well). The same thing still applies though, incrementing the object (or any other operation apart from destroying it) will not change the object's address.